# dbrda variance summary table distance euclidean

Tags: r, anova, vegan

I am attaching this example because I would like to know how you interpret the variance in the summary table of the dbrda:

```
    data(varespec)

data(varechem)
vare.cca <- dbrda(varespec ~ N + P + K + Condition(Al), varechem,
                  dist="euclidean")
anova(vare.cca, by ="margin")
```

```
         Df Variance      F Pr(>F)  
N         1   156.26 3.0261  0.032 *
P         1    71.85 1.3914  0.239  
K         1    94.12 1.8227  0.150  
Residual 19   981.12
```

Is the variance in the output the percentage of variance explain or it needs to be divided by 100?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Variance is variance. That is sum of squared differences of observed and predicted values divided with degrees of freedom. `dbrda` with Euclidean distances is identical to `rda` of rectangular matrix, also for the variance.